# Parameterized Query - M language (Excel)

Tags: mysql, excel, powerquery, m

I'm trying to make my query parameterized; meaning once the value in a specific cell is set it will be the value of which the query will run.

My problem is the value in the cell is date and MySQL doesn't understand the format

This is the query I'm using:

```
Select * From ID WHERE `TIME` = '2019-08-26';
```

What i did is that i went to excel and created a table using "get data from table/range" option, so this table perform the filtration or the value i want to perform my query with.

After that i went into power query and changed the value of "Time" in my query to this so it becomes dynamic

```
`TIME`= " & Text.From(X) & ";"])
```

Now the value in my table becomes the dynamic filter.

Then went into advance editor and added the following:

```
    let 
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1_2"]}[Content],
    x= Source1{0}[Date],
```

Table1_2 Being the table i created (using get data option)

[Date] is the header of the table mentioned above

When I've done that, power query reads the query as the following, assuming that The value in my table (parameter) = 2019-01-01:

```
SELECT * FROM ID WHERE `TIME` = 2019/01/01
```

Which returns an empty table because the data format in my DB is YYYY-MM-DD

That is the first problem that i faced the **second** one was:

That i want my query to filter based on a range between the data inserted in the cell and the day after it (adding one day to the value in the cell) meaning that the value in the table (filter/Parameter) becomes a range for example:

The value in the cell = 2019-01-01

The query should become

```
SELECT * FROM ID WHERE `TIME` > '2019-01-01' AND `TIME` < '2019-01-02'
```

I've tired change the time into this:

```
    `TIME` > " & Text.From(Date.ToText((x),"YYYY-MM-DD"))& " 
and `TIME` < "& Text.From(Date.ToText((Date.AddDays(x,1)),"YYYY-MM-DD")) &";"])
```

Power Query still won't give me any results since excel completely ignores what i did as the tables comes back with wrong values.

Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this?

Comment: `TIME` is a string column? If so, you'll either need to update your query to change the format from what your Excel workbook has to whatever your DB expects, or update your Excel workbook to have the column in that format originally.

Comment: its date time format but i don't understand how excel is failing to understand it

Comment: Can you paste your whole M query code?

Comment: = MySQL.Database("db2.com", "clients", [ReturnSingleDatabase=true, Query="SELECT login,TIME, deposit FROM ID #(lf)where `TIME` > " & Text.From(x) & " and `TIME` < " & Text.From(Date.AddDays(x,1)) & ";"])


and from the advanced editor this how it looks like

Comment: let
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2_2"]}[Content],
    x= Source1{0}[date],
    Source = MySQL.Database("db2.com", "clients", [ReturnSingleDatabase=true, Query="SELECT login,TIME, deposit FROM ID #(lf)where `TIME` > " & Text.From(x) & " and `TIME` < " & Text.From(Date.AddDays(x,1)) & ";"])
in
    Source

Comment: and the following is the message i get 
 Message=You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12:00:00 AM and `TIME` < 8/29/2019 12:00:00 AM' at line 3
    ErrorCode=-2147467259

Answer (score 0):

The `Date.ToText` format is (case sensitive)

```
Date.ToText(x, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

and let

```
`TIME` = "' & Date.ToText(x, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "';"
```

for the SQL. Be sure to include the `'`

Since you are using `Date.ToText`, you can omit `Text.From`